# Dropdown is still disable even after selecting a value

Tags: javascript, angular, disabled-input

There are two dropdown buttons d1 and d2. d2 is disabled. After selecting a value from 'd1', 'd2' is still disabled.

```
<div class="card-container">
        <label>Country</label>
        <select placeholder="Country" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (change)="changeCountry($event)" >
            <option>--Choose Country--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let country of Countries" >{{country.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="card-container">
        <label>State</label>
        <select placeholder="State" (change)="changeState($event)"
      [disabled]="selectedCountry">
            <option>--Choose State--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let state of states">{{state.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

On using [disabled]="selectedCountry" d2 is disabled but not disable if [disabled]="!selectedCountry"
I want to make d2 selectable only if d1 is selected.

Comment: `[disabled]="!selectedCountry"` is that you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[disabled]="selectedCountry"` means if you have some value for `selectedCountry` it will be `true`, which means its disabled. So the condition should be the reverse

```
[disabled]="!selectedCountry"
```

will make it disabled if the `selectedCountry` doesnt have any value.

```
<div class="card-container">
  <label>Country</label>
  <select placeholder="Country" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (change)="changeCountry($event)" >
    <option>--Choose Country--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let country of Countries" >{{country.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="card-container">
  <label>State</label>
  <select placeholder="State" (change)="changeState($event)" [disabled]="!selectedCountry">
    <option>--Choose State--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let state of states">{{state.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

also make sure the inital value of `selectedCountry` to be `selectedCountry = ''`